# Java converting unix time to date different on each computer,why?

Tags: java, date, unix-timestamp

i have weird situation i have simple code that looks like this :

```
Date d = new Date(1308670980000L);
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy,HH:mm");
String s = f.format(d);
```

some computers im getting : 21.06.2011 15:43 and this is the date that 
im expecting to get and its fine .
but on other pc's im getting :21.06.2011,18:43 i dont know why im getting this date.
what can be wrong in the pc or java configuration that gives me this ?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the two computers have their clocks set to different time zones.

Comment: where can i fix the time zone?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the default timezone.

If you want the GMT time you need to do something like this:

```
Date d = new Date(1308670980000L);
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy,HH:mm");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
String s = f.format(d);
```

Comment: hi , i removed the accept , beaocse in my pc it fixed the problem 
but in others the time is still wrong and its dosn't do any thing
its just dosn't work , what else can it be ?

Comment: The result of `s` in this code must return the exact same on every machine